# Is it bad practice to require the same module in multiple files in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, programming-practices, node.js

Let’s say I have three files, all of which import a fairly large module. But I’ve divided them because they have different functions.  Now each of the JavaScript files needs an initial statement like

```
const a = require('./')
```

Is this considered bad practice?

Comment: Are you using Require.js to import modules?

Comment: When importing files with duplicate imports, do you see more than one request for that resource?

Comment: I'm not using Require.js to my knowledge. In my package.json file, I have the module listed under "dependencies". I'm not sure how to view requests for a certain resource.

Comment: Is this code used in a web browser? Server side? Both?

Comment: It's a Node.js file, so I think it's server side. I'm new to javascript, by the way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry about that.

A first `require` involves a bunch of input/output operations in order to find the matching file and read it into memory. “[Any performance impact here will be inconsequential relative to everything else the server is doing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34955269/240613)” Given that JavaScript modules rarely exceed several megabytes in size, the performance impact of the operation is close to zero.

A second `require` to the very same module won't even involve that. Since it's already in memory, it is unnecessary to find it on disk or read the actual file. So the performance footprint is even smaller (and much smaller!) than when the module was `require`d for the first time.

If you want to see how it works, create a script which, in a loop, `require`s the same module many times. Vary the number of iterations and see how it impacts the time spent inside the loop.